# Taking Integration Error

Tags: matlab, math, integral

I'm new at MATLAB. I want to write code of this equations.

[image]

I tried with below code which is written by me.

```
k=-6:6;
n=-6:6
x= double(k>=0);
h=10*exp(-10*(n-k)).*double((n<=0));
fonk=double(k>=0).*(10*exp(-10*(n-k)).*double(k-n>=0));
for n=1:5
   y=integral(@(k)fonk(k,n),6,6);

stem((-6:-6),y);
```

But It gives

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in untitled2>@(k)fonk(k,n) (line 10)
y=integral(@(k)fonk(k,n),1,6);

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
            fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 133)
        [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 76)
    [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
 Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in untitled2 (line 10)
 y=integral(@(k)fonk(k,n),1,6);
```

errors. I have been googling for this error but I cant find solution. Thanks for Helping.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your 5th line should be sufficient. You don't need 1~4th lines.

```
fonk=@(kv,nv) double(kv>=0).*(10*exp(-10*(nv-kv)).*double(kv-nv>=0));

for n=1:5
    y(n)=integral(@(z) fonk(z,n),-6,6);
end

stem(y)
```

You need to define `fonk` as a function that takes two arguments otherwise `integral` does not understand it. Also you need to use a vector form of `y` to store results.